# Are there different difficulty settings?

Tags: assassins-creed-2

I started yesterday Assassin's Creed 2 on PC. I don't remember that the game asked me to select a difficulty setting at start. Is this available?

I am asking it because the fights I did in the first 2 hours I played were really easy. Are the fights more difficult when the adventure proceed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there's no way to select a difficulty level in the game. You're right, the combat is not that difficult, especially when you get used to using counter-kills and are good at blocking But later on you will be facing more enemies at a time and every time you make a mistake you will lose health, so you do have to be careful. I can't remember ever actually dying in combat, though.

I don't remember about the first game, but there is also no difficulty selection in Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood (the 3rd in the series).

Comment: No difficulty selection in AC1 either.

Comment: When will Ubisoft understand that not all gamers are casual? Thank you for answer.

Comment: @Drake, they've made Ezio such a proficient fighter that he could be up against 50 guys and you could get through it just fine by being careful and counter-killing. There's no sense of danger. It would have been interesting to have fighting as a last resort, with more focus on defensive things like smoke bombs, stealth takedowns and hiding bodies to ensure you only ever face a couple of people at a time. That way, when you *do* have to sneak into a compound and assassinate someone you're always on your toes to avoid alerting anyone. Just my 2 cents, I still enjoyed the games :)

Comment: Personally I think the AC games are just for the puzzles / fun (running, jumping, climbing, etc), not the difficulty of fighting, or avoiding enemies.

Answer (score 1):

you want higher difficulty, just try to finish the target without actually killing or alerting any other guard as much as possible... thts all about difficulty is AC2..